# Proving a set contains the product algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

The stuff in this question came from a measure theory course notes pdf (link below). The proof of the theorem I am interested is also included in this pdf but it is quite short and skips over details. I filled in the details and present my proof and it would be great if some experience proof writers can give it a look.

[https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch5.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch5.pdf)

---

**Defn 1: Measurable Rectangles**

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ are measurable spaces, then a measurable rectangle is a subset $A\times B$  of $X\times Y$ where $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and $B\in \mathcal{B}$ are measurable subsets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

---

**Defn 2: Product $\sigma$-algebra**

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ are measurable spaces. The product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$ generated by the collection of all measurable rectangles,
$$
A\otimes \mathcal{B}=\sigma(\{A\times B:A\in \mathcal{A},B\in \mathcal{B}\}).
$$
The product of $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ is the measurable space $(X\times Y,\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B})$

---

**Defn 3: Sections**

Suppose that $E\subset X\times Y$. For any $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, we define the $x$-section $E_x\subset Y$ and then $y$-section $E^y\subset X$ of $E$ by
$$
E_x=\{y\in Y: (x,y)\in E\},\ \ \ E_y=\{x\in X: (x,y)\in E\}
$$

---

**Thm : Generator of Product $\sigma$-algebra**

If $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ are measurable spaces and $E\in \mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}$, then $E_x\in \mathcal{B}$ is for every $x\in X$ and $E_y\in \mathcal{A}$ for every $y\in Y$. In mathematical symbols:
$$
{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{M}= \{E\subset X\times Y: E_x\in \mathcal{B},\ \forall x\in X\text{ and }E_y\in \mathcal{A},\ \forall y \in Y\}
$$

*Proof*

Fix $E=A\times B\subset X\times Y$. Let $E\in \{A\times B:A\in \mathcal{A},B\in \mathcal{B}\}$.

If $(x,y)\in E$, then $E_x=B$ and $E_y=A$. This proves that $\mathcal{M}$ contains the generator of $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}$ (the collection of measurable rectangles).

Next, we prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, this completes the proof that
$$
A\otimes B\subset \mathcal{M}
$$

Let $A\times B\in \mathcal{M}$.

1. Closure under complements. Recall
   $$
   (A\times B)^c=(A^c\times B)\cup (A\times B^c)\cup (A^c\times B^c)
   $$
   It is clear that either $(E^c)_x=E_x$ or $(E^c)_x=E_x^c$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $E_x\in \mathcal{B}\implies E_x^c\in \mathcal{B}$. The arugument is similar for $E_y$.
2. Closure under countable union. We have
   $$
   \Big[\bigcup_i^n (A_i\times B_i)\Big]_x=\bigcup_i^n E_{x,i}\in \mathcal{B}
   $$
   because $\mathcal{B}$ is $\sigma$-algebra. The arugument is similar for $E_y$. $\blacksquare$

---

Comment: What is $\mathcal M$? The set of measurable rectangles is not closed under complement nor union.

Comment: $\mathcal{M}$ is the set on right side (edited this in). Yes, but the $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ are closed under complement and union because they are sigma algebras.

Comment: Ok. I thought $\mathcal M$ was the set of measurable rectangles. This way the statements are correct, but then you should prove that $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, picking arbitrary and not specific elements of that.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean I shouldn't pick specific elements?

Comment: Not all the elements of $\mathcal M$ are rectangles. Consider e.g. a disk in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. You should prove that its complement is again in $\mathcal M$. Similarly for the countable union.

Comment: But I didn't assume  $\mathcal{M}$  are the sets of rectangles. I only used the definition of $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: In your proofs 1. and 2. for me it seems you did. The statement is that $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Note $\mathcal M$ might be strictly bigger than $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B$, and is thus *not* necessarily generated by rectangles.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B$ is by definition the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the measurable rectangles, proving that $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra will indeed imply $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal M$, as it also contains every measurable rectangles.

However in your proof you start out with specific elements of $\mathcal M$ (the rectangles) instead of generic elements.

What you should rather do is

1. Assume $E\in\mathcal M$ is arbitrary, and prove that $E^c\in\mathcal M$.
2. Assume $E_n\in\mathcal M$ are arbitrary, and prove that $\bigcup_nE_n\in\mathcal M$.

Comment: I mean if $E$ is not a rectangle then $E_x$ and $E_y$ would be empty.

Comment: Why? Not empty, but they can vary. What if $E$ is a disk in $\Bbb R\times R$?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean a disk in $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}$.

Comment: Does my argument not work when $E$ is not a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same argument. Or even simpler.